# resolveContextualObject and getConversationId in custom Spring scope

Tags: spring

I am wondering what is the purpose of `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope.resolveContextualObject(String key)` and `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope.getConversationId()`?

From the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/Scope.html):

> Object resolveContextualObject(String key)
>
> Resolve the contextual object for the given key, if any. E.g. the  HttpServletRequest object for key "request".
>
> String getConversationId()
>
> Return the conversation ID for the current underlying scope, if any.
>   The exact meaning of the conversation ID depends on the underlying storage mechanism. In the case of session-scoped objects, the conversation ID would typically be equal to (or derived from) the session ID; in the case of a custom conversation that sits within the overall session, the specific ID for the current conversation would be appropriate.

This description doesn't tell me much.
Could you give me some examples which demonstrate how to make use of these methods?

My observation is that `resolveContextualObject(String key)` looks like a code smell, where where a Scope can expose some internal object.

Comment: That is the whole point of the `resolveContextualObject` to retrieve the actual object needed by the scoped proxy to execute the operation on.

Answer (score 0):

Having:

```
public class MyCustomScope implements Scope {

    private Pair<String, String> myPair;

    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
        if ("myKey".equals(key)) return myPair;
        return null;
    }

    // ...
}

@Configuration
public class RegisterMyScopeConfig {

    @Bean
    public BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor() {
        return beanFactory -> beanFactory.registerScope(
            "mycustomscope", new MyCustomScope()); 
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
@Scope("mycustomscope")
@Component 
class MyComponent {

    @Value("#{myKey.first}")
    private String firstOfMyPair;

    // or 

    @Value("#{myKey}")
    private Pair<String,String> myPair;
}
```

Of course the way how you resolved object which matches key, might be fancier ;). 
For example, in [GenericScope](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/GenericScope.java) it looks like that:

```
@Override
public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
    Expression expression = parseExpression(key);
    return expression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, this.beanFactory);
}
```